# SQL Replace call in dynamic SQL

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to update rows of data with a replacement string (built by another SP).  I have the following table of data that shows a default expacct and replacement glseg1 and glseg2 values:

[image: Account Structure Table]

What I am trying to accomplish is updating the expacct number with an updated expacct number generated by the ReplacementString.  The ReplacementString is in a table and associated with the default expacct:

[image]

Each section of the expacct (the number set between each hyphen) can be updated. 
 In a nutshell, for each section of the expacct, the ReplacementString should take the default expacct, use what is there currently if overwriting is not allowed (i.e., substring('@Acct',1,4)) or overwrite with the value from the designated glseg column, using the default value if no glseg value exists (i.e., rtrim(ltrim(isnull(nullif(d.glseg2, ''), substring('@Acct',10,4)))))

I have a somewhat working version of code but the replacement string is not being updated for each row that is being updated, it appears that the ReplacementString being used is the last one in the above table.

What I need to see in this output table is the expacct for ID 1 to be 6720-010-0000 (default value for first set, glseg1 value for second set and 0000 for third set since glseg2 is empty).  The updated expacct value for the row with ID 2 is correct.

We have to support SQL back to 2008 R2 so please limit solutions to those that work with SQL 2008 R2.

[image]

Here is the complete SQL code I currently have:

```
if object_id(N'tempdb..#TimeData') is not null drop table #TimeData
create table #TimeData(ID int, expacct varchar(45), glseg1 varchar(10), glseg2 varchar(10))
insert into #TimeData
values(1, '6720-000-0000', '010', '')
    , (2, '6720-999-0000', '030', '0404')
select * from #TimeData

-- create table of all possible account numbers from ALL_TimeCardDetail with their associated replacement strings
if object_id(N'tempdb..#AccountNumbers') is not null drop table #AccountNumbers
create table #AccountNumbers(Original varchar(100), ReplacementString nvarchar(max), Updated varchar(100))

insert into #AccountNumbers
values('6720-000-0000', 'substring(''@Acct'',1,4) + ''-'' + rtrim(ltrim(isnull(nullif(d.glseg1, ''''), substring(''@Acct'',6,3)))) + ''-'' + rtrim(ltrim(isnull(nullif(d.glseg2, ''''), substring(''@Acct'',10,4))))', '')
, ('6720-999-0000', 'substring(''@Acct'',1,4) + ''-'' + substring(''@Acct'',6,3) + ''-'' + rtrim(ltrim(isnull(nullif(d.glseg2, ''''), substring(''@Acct'',10,4))))', '')

select * from #AccountNumbers


declare @cmd nvarchar(max)
select @cmd = N'update #TimeData set expacct = ' + replace(n.ReplacementString, '@Acct', d.expacct) + '
from #TimeData d
    inner join #AccountNumbers n
        on d.expacct = n.Original'
from #TimeData d
    inner join #AccountNumbers n
        on d.expacct = n.Original

print @cmd
exec (@cmd)

select * from #TimeData
```

Comment: Hi.  I'm not sure what you are trying to do.  If I understand well, 010 must be replaced be nothing, and 030 by 0404?  But you didn't use 010 or 030 in your example!
Please post what is the expected result.

Comment: Eugh. This is a whole new level of SQL injection possibilities. Please secure that table with the replacement strings with your life, and put auditing on it for good measure. Actually, strongly consider abandoning this instead -- how many different replacement strings do you *really* need, and can't you reduce this to a few cases that you encode with a simple number and switch on with `CASE`? Or how about using good ol' client-processed regexes (and if the data can't leave the database, using CLR assemblies to get the regex functionality into SQL)?

Comment: @DanielBlais Please see the paragraph that starts with "What I need to see in this output table is .."  ( I broke it out to its own paragraph to make it more obvious).

Comment: I copy-paste-run your code, and I got your expected result.  1 = 6720-999-0000 and 2 = 6720-999-0404.

Comment: @DanielBlais The result I need for ID 1 is  6720-010-0000, not 6720-999-0000.  There are two different replacement string values and it is only using the last one to do all the replacements.

Comment: The issue is, select @cmd = N'update ... will store latest update command into @ cmd.  When you run this query, it will be based on the last result.
You have to use another logic, or use a cursor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works, but is not optimal for performance point of view :

```
SET NOCOUNT OFF

if object_id(N'tempdb..#TimeData') is not null drop table #TimeData
create table #TimeData(ID int, expacct varchar(45), glseg1 varchar(10), glseg2 varchar(10))
insert into #TimeData
values(1, '6720-000-0000', '010', '')
    , (2, '6720-999-0000', '030', '0404')
select * from #TimeData

-- create table of all possible account numbers from ALL_TimeCardDetail with their associated replacement strings
if object_id(N'tempdb..#AccountNumbers') is not null drop table #AccountNumbers
create table #AccountNumbers(id int identity, Original varchar(100), ReplacementString nvarchar(max), Updated varchar(100))

insert into #AccountNumbers (original, ReplacementString, updated)
values('6720-000-0000', 'substring(''@Acct'',1,4) + ''-'' + rtrim(ltrim(isnull(nullif(d.glseg1, ''''), substring(''@Acct'',6,3)))) + ''-'' + rtrim(ltrim(isnull(nullif(d.glseg2, ''''), substring(''@Acct'',10,4))))', '')
, ('6720-999-0000', 'substring(''@Acct'',1,4) + ''-'' + substring(''@Acct'',6,3) + ''-'' + rtrim(ltrim(isnull(nullif(d.glseg2, ''''), substring(''@Acct'',10,4))))', '')

select * from #AccountNumbers

declare @cmd nvarchar(max)
declare @id int
declare c cursor for select id from #AccountNumbers
open c
fetch next from c into @id
while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
begin
    select @cmd = N'update #TimeData set expacct = ' + replace(n.ReplacementString, '@Acct', d.expacct) + '
    from #TimeData d
        inner join #AccountNumbers n
            on d.expacct = n.Original
    where n.id = ' + convert(varchar, @id)
    from #TimeData d
        inner join #AccountNumbers n
            on d.expacct = n.Original
    where n.id = @id
    print @cmd
    exec (@cmd)

    fetch next from c into @id
end
close c
deallocate c

select * from #TimeData
```